# Flutter: Responsive Web - Multiple Listviews in a Column

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am working on a flutter web application and need to place multiple list views in a column.
I am trying to use responsive-framework. But it doesn't seem to work with my project. I tried Wrap widget. I doesn't work either.

What I want to do is moving around the list views based on the screen size.

```
   Just one Column                   two Columns for wider screen

     |  1  |                         |  1  | |  5  |
     |  2  |                         |  2  | |  6  | 
     |  3  |             =>          |  3  |
     |  4  |                         |  4  |
     |  5  |
     |  6  |

This order of the list views should be exactly what I illustrated above.
Below is not what I need.

    |  1  | |  2  |
    |  3  | |  4  |
    |  5  | |  6  |
    |  7  |
```

Any tips??

Answer (score 1):

Try GridView. There's a lot to it depending on your requirements for the Container Size.  But GridView.builder with SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent (there are other variants).

You'll need to change the axis direction to horizontal in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this using the responsive_framework package
[responsive_framework](https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_framework)

Example:

```
...
      body: Center(
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: ResponsiveBreakpoints.of(context).smallerThan(DESKTOP)
            ?

            //Mobile or Tablet UI
            //Return 1 Column with all fields
            ListView(
                        children: [
                          //field 1
                          TextFormField(),
                          //field 2
                          TextFormField(),
                          //field 3
                          TextFormField(),
                          //field 4
                          TextFormField(),
                          //field 5
                          TextFormField(),
                          //field 6
                          TextFormField(),
                          //field 7
                          TextFormField(),
                        ],
                      )
            :

            //Is desktop. Arrange in 2 Columns
            ResponsiveRowColumn(
                layout: ResponsiveRowColumnType.ROW,
                children: [
                  //1st column
                  ResponsiveRowColumnItem(
                      rowFlex: 1,
                      child: ListView(
                        children: [
                          //field 1
                          TextFormField(),
                          //field 2
                          TextFormField(),
                          //field 3
                          TextFormField(),
                          //field 4
                          TextFormField(),
                        ],
                      )),
                  //2nd column
                  ResponsiveRowColumnItem(
                      rowFlex: 1,
                      child: ListView(
                        children: [
                          //field 5
                          TextFormField(),
                          //field 6
                          TextFormField(),
                          //field 7
                          TextFormField(),
                        ],
                      )),
                ],
              ),
      ),
    ),
...
```